# struts 2 for loop

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, iterator

I want to loop a code some no of  times like this

```
<s:iterator value="#session.count">
        <TD WIDTH='10%' BGCOLOR='#000080'>&nbsp;</TD>
    </s:iterator>
```

based on value 'count', stored in the session, those many times I need to add  tags as above
but it is not looping as expected.

what I want to know is 
 is for arrays or collection objects. 
but
how to loop the code N no of time using Struts 2 tags in JSP.

Comment: What is the value you are getting for count? Did you print it? http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/

Comment: hi @thinkSteep  thanks for your reply. the value of count is just int. between 1 to 100. for example if it 50 I need to loop the code 50 times. I know iterating List object as in the example in the link you have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it is very easy.

use this:

```
<s:subset source="your_source" count="#session.count">
    <s:iterator>
        <td>test</td>
    </s:iterator>
</s:subset>
```

Comment: what if 'your_source' is a int.? like plane java.. for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ // loop code.} this 'n' comes from session object.I need  struts2 tag with this  type of for loop .

Comment: @MadhuB Accepting this answer makes no sense, since you have no source, and just want to iterate `n` times. This only does that if you have a collection with at least `n` entries.

Answer (score 6):

For a simple for-loop, use the `begin` and `end` attributes:

```html
<s:iterator begin="0" end="%{#session.count}">
  <td width='10%' bgcolor='#000080'>&nbsp;</td>
</s:iterator>
```

<sub>*I'd also use CSS a bit better.*</sub>

See the [iterator tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html).

---

Now you've mentioned you're using a very old version of S2. In that case, use [JSTL's `c:forEach` tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html), there's no reason to use an S2 tag. It has the same begin/end semantics, and still makes much for sense than creating a useless list.

Comment: The begin, end and step attributes are only available from 2.1.7 on.. I am using Struts 2.0.11.

Comment: @MadhuB That kind of info is something you'd want to put in your question, *particularly* when it's that old of a version. You really need to not use that version in production. Not upgrading, especially when there are security issues, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `iterator` examples [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html).

Comment: Links with page not found!